# Durandal routing with parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, durandal

I have a Durandal application having routing like below.

```
activate: function () {
    return router.map([{
        route: 'friends',
        moduleId: 'viewmodels/friends',
        nav: true
    }, {
        route: 'about',
        moduleId: 'viewmodels/about',
        nav: true
    }, {
        route: '(:id)',
        title: 'TimeLine',
        moduleId: 'viewmodels/Posts',
        nav: true
    }, ]).buildNavigationModel()
        .activate();
```

But each time we navigate to 'friends',or 'about' it goes to 'viewmodel/Post' with 'friends' and 'about' key words are as 'id'.I cant go to 'viewmodels/friends' and 'viewmodels/about'.Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Durandal may be interpreting your posts route as the default route. Try changing it to `posts/(:id)` and specify another route as the default route (by setting the route property to `''`).

Comment: Dont use a route like `'(:id)'` silly. You are telling Durandal that no matter what the route is, go to `viewmodels/Posts`.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that in `viewmodels/` you have a file named `posts.js` and your moduleId is `moduleId: 'viewmodels/posts'` not `moduleId: 'viewmodels/Posts'` and `posts.js` it has to be the same

Change your code to this:

```
activate: function () {
    return router.map([{
        route: ['', 'friends'],//this is the home route ['', 'routeName']
        moduleId: 'viewmodels/friends',
        nav: true
    }, {
        route: 'about',
        moduleId: 'viewmodels/about',
        nav: true
    }, {
        route: 'posts/(:id)',// and change this from (:id) to posts/:id or posts/(:id)
        title: 'TimeLine',
        moduleId: 'viewmodels/posts',
        nav: true
    }, ]).buildNavigationModel()
        .activate();
```

and in your `posts.js` you can access `id's` like this

```
var postId;
function activate(id) {
        postId = id;
        logger.log(viewModel.title + "'s  View Activated", null, viewModel.title, true);
        return true;
    }

function attached(view, parent) {
        alert(postId);
}

var viewModel = {
        activate: activate,
        title: 'singlePost',
        attached: attached
}

return viewModel;
```

read more on [Mapping Routes](http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Using-The-Router.html)